# Local storage back button show previous page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Question to local storage. Assumning I have a web page index.html from where I can click a link a will be redirected to mypage.html. How could I set my local storage so that, when clicking back button on mypage.html I'll be redired back to my index.html? Is it possible? 
Should it be done within my "private" back button or is possible to use browser's back button? 
Or is it possbile to write something like:

```
localStorage.setItem("index", index.html)
```

Do you maybe have an example?

Edit:
I know about window.history.back(); I just want to use local storage to get the page state.

Comment: You're just trying to emulate the "back" browser button that everyone uses... What's your point?

Comment: Just courius how to get sesson state from previous page using LS.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override a browser's back button. You can add a menu in your page; by clicking on that it can be achieved.

```
 window.history.back()
```

is the method used to go back.

Answer (score 0):

There's perhaps no need in localStorage. Just use `history.back();` or `window.history.back();`. You may need to check the referrer prior to that.

- Check if the user came from `index.html`
- use the method described above